# Error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" even after setting headers on server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a NodeJS/Express backend API server running on port 8002 and a ReactJS frontEnd app on port 3000.

I am submitting a form from the reactJS frontend app to post on the API server which saves it to a database.

I call a function saveAndContinue to submit the form.

Below is the snippet that does that :

```
class Confirmation extends Component{
saveAndContinue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("props : " + JSON.stringify(this.props.values));
    var form_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000); 
    let headers = new Headers();

      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    fetch("http://localhost:8002/sharepoint/big_data_poc/" + form_id,{
        method:'POST',
        //mode: 'cors',
        body:JSON.stringify(this.props.values),
        headers: headers
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(this.setState({confirmation_id:form_id}))
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    this.props.nextStep();
}
```

Also I added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the nodeJS server response header

```
cb_service.prototype.addForm = function(req,res,form_id, doc_type,payload){
logger.info(JSON.stringify(payload));
bucket.upsert(form_id,payload,function(err,result){
    if(err){
        logger.error("error inserting data in couchbase")
    }
    else {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT')
        res.setHeader('mode','cors')
        logger.info("successful inserts");
        res.status(200);

        return res.json({"success":"ok"});       
    }
 })
}
```

I don't see any request coming into the server at all. I just see the below error in the browser console :

> Failed to load http://localhost:8002/sharepoint/big_data_poc/944960: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any help is most appreciated!!  I think I have done everything that's recommended by the similar questions on SO. Even Safari throws the below error :

> [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (408661, line 0)
>
> [Error] Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8002/sharepoint/big_data_poc/408661. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `cors` and you wont be any problems `const cors = require('cors'); app.use(cors());` link on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Is this on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add those middleware to your app

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
```

});

Comment: Is this on the server side?

Comment: Yes try to add this to your backend :)